# Alter table add column with data computed from the same table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with column "datetime2_asstring". I would like to add a column "datetime2_asdatetime2" to that table.

For this I execute queries:

1) add column datetime2_asdatetime2

2) update column datetime2_asdatetime2 with values from cast(datetime_asstring TO datetime2)

I wonder if there is SQL Syntax to add a column and at the same time set computed value for every row on this column in the table, all in one query (ALTER TABLE) in SQL Server?

Comment: Which version of Sql Server?

Comment: Sql server 2012 , but if you have solution for 2005 and upper it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below would work for the versions that you have specified:

```
ALTER TABLE datetime2_asstring 
ADD datetime2_asdatetime2 AS CAST(datetime_asstring AS datetime2)
```